# google cloud sql access denied for application deployed in google app engine

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, cloud

I have Google app engine application that uses google cloud sql, it works locally but when deployed on the google app engine cloud I get access denied. locally i have defined ip address to access sql cloud and for the app engine app the application id is define. is there any other config that is missing, why the code is not working deploy on the google cloud?

Comment: If the application id is listed among those in `Authorized App Engine applications` on the `Google Developers Console`, it should work.  Check the `Applications` in your Cloud SQL instance dashboard, just in case there was a typo somewhere...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, do you have small java app that uses google cloud sql with JPA and Ecliselink implementation. I would like to load and see how it works.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Java, so I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a password?  Don't.  When app is deployed in GAE and you use a password for cloud sql it will give you an access denied error.  If you null out your password before you deploy, it will work.  The password is only required if you are not using GAE.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a few reasons that are preventing your GAE instance to connect to your GCS instance:

- The App Engine app [is not configured](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/#Python_Grant_your_App_Engine_application_access_to_the_Google%20Cloud%20SQL_instance) to have permissions to GCS
- Your GCS url is not in the form: `/cloudsql/your-project-id:your-instance-name`
- Your MySQL user was not created using the Cloud SQL administration console.
- You are using a password to connect (you shouldn't)